# Appropriate way of connecting to Data source while using Data Link Properties in C#

Tags: c#, database, datasource

I am using Data Link Properties in my C# windows application, to allow the user to connect to variety of Data Source and to read the data from the same.

The problem that I am facing is when user tries to connect via Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC drivers; connection string gets formed successfully but while reading the data my application throws an error

> The .Net Framework Data Provider for OLEDB (System.Data.OleDb) does not support the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers (MSDASQL). Use the .Net Framework Data Provider for ODBC (System.Data.Odbc).'

The connection string that is formed via ODBC drivers is

> Provider=MSDASQL.1;Password=abclogin;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=abclogin;Data Source=Integrator;Initial Catalog=TempDataBase

In my code I am using OleDbConnection  to Data source

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(localConnString)
```

What is the appropriate way to connect to Data source while using Data Link Properties so that user can connect to any data source the code will not fail in any of the cases.

Comment: Is that `localConnString` may contain connection strings with DSN parameter or ODBC driver? If it's true, probably you should put `if` condition based on connection string used to initialize either `System.Data.OleDb` or `System.Data.Odbc` provider.

Comment: Yes localconnectionstring is a variable whichcontains connection string.

Comment: So the only solution is to use if condition?

Comment: I prefer to use it by checking certain elements or patterns inside connection string which doesn't match acceptable OLEDB connection strings, then use `OdbcConnection` instead of `OleDbConnection`.